# Camel CxfEndpoint set address doesnt work after first call

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, cxf

I want to set address every time i reach my endpoint bean. When i call setAddress first time it works, after that address and endpoint url changes but ws call gone to first addres. here is my code

```
@Bean
public CxfEndpoint xWSwithoutAddress() {
    final CxfEndpoint endpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
    endpoint.setServiceClass(IntegrationSoap.class);
    return endpoint;
}

@Bean
@Scope(value="prototype",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public CxfEndpoint xWS() {
    XSettings settings = configFileManager.readSettings(XSettings.class);
    final CxfEndpoint endpoint = xWSwithoutAddress();
    endpoint.setAddress(settings.getWsdlAddress());
    return endpoint;
}
```

and route

```
from("direct:getEbysServices")
        .to("cxf:bean:xWS?wrapped=true&loggingFeatureEnabled=true");
```

Comment: You make sure to request a new bean from spring context each time you need to connect to the CXFEndPoint? It works if you use directly `endpoint=xWSwithoutAddress(); endpoint.setAddress(settings.getWsdlAddress());` as a new instance instead of using @Bean?

Comment: You could use the [dynamic routing](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html). In you route you may change the property `wsdlURL` of you cxf-endpoint as documented [here](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html).

Comment: new instance doesn't work correctly. @pedrofb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping and starting route solves my issue.

I give route an id

```
from("direct:getEbysServices")
        .routeId("ebysRoute")
        .to("cxf:bean:xWS?wrapped=true&loggingFeatureEnabled=true");
```

and when address changes i stop and start route.

```
camelContext.stopRoute("ebysRoute");
camelContext.startRoute("ebysRoute");
```